# How to use id and class together in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to use id and class together in js for AutoClick script.

For ex.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('style-scope ytcp-comment-creator-heart');
for (var i = 0;; i++) {    
  items[i].click();
}
```

but here is only class I am using,
I want to use here Both Class and ID together is it possible, Then how?

Comment: querySelector / querySelectorAll is probably what you want to search for in your research to this vague question

Comment: Why not use only the ID?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here bud? Are you trying to add items with certain IDs to a list of items with a certain classname?

Comment: ID have to be unique - even when there are same IDs, getElementById returns just 1.